# how to add ViewPager with SherlockFragment tabs in android

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public class FragmentLifenews extends SherlockFragment {
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public FragmentLifenews() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_life, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPager1(getFragmentManager()));
        addActionBarTabs();

        return view;
    }

    private ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    private void addActionBarTabs() {
        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
        getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
        getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
        String[] tabs = { "Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3" };
        for (String tabTitle : tabs) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(tabTitle)
                    .setTabListener(tabListener);
            actionBar.addTab(tab);
        }
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    }

    private ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    };



public class ViewPager1 extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final int PAGES = 3;

    public ViewPager1(FragmentManager actionBar) {
        super(actionBar);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1Fragment();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2Fragment();
            case 2:
                return new Tab3Fragment();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The item position should be less or equal to:" + PAGES);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES;
    }
```

`FragmentLifenews` is class which extends from `SherlockFragment`. I want to add `ViewPager`  with `SherlockFragment`  tabs but i am unable to get i am getting error at:

```
   com.locii.fragment.FragmentLifenews.onCreateView(FragmentLifenews.java:28) 
   viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
   viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPager1(getFragmentManager()));
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong i have changed `getFragmentManager()` in place of `getSupportActionBar()` please suggest me .

Answer (score 0):

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {

```
MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    // Tab Initialization
    initialiseTabHost();

    // Fragments and ViewPager Initialization
    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
}

// Method to add a TabHost
private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec) {
    tabSpec.setContent(new MyTabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

// Manages the Tab changes, synchronizing it with Pages
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    // mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
    setSelectedTabColor();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}

// Manages the Page changes, synchronizing it with Tabs
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);
    // mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
private void setSelectedTabColor() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(
                android.R.color.transparent);
        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        mTabHost.getTabWidget()
                .setShowDividers(TabWidget.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bottom_home_back);
        // mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width =
        // 50;
    }
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_selected);
    // mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 50;
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    // TODO Put here your Fragments
    // DealTab f1 = DealTab.newInstance();
    DealTab_New f1 = DealTab_New.newInstance();
    EventTab f2 = EventTab.newInstance();

    MyAccountFragment f3 = MyAccountFragment.newInstance();
    MessageFragment f4 = MessageFragment.newInstance();
    MoreFragment f5 = MoreFragment.newInstance();
    QrCodeFragment f6 = QrCodeFragment.newInstance();

    // fList.add(f1);
    fList.add(f1);
    fList.add(f2);
    fList.add(f3);
    fList.add(f4);
    fList.add(f5);
    fList.add(f6);

    return fList;
}

// Tabs Creation
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
private void initialiseTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    // TODO Put here your Tabs
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_deals)));


    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_event)));
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_my_account)));
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_message)));
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_more)));

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    setSelectedTabColor();
}
```

}
i use in this my Application to use tab host and also view pager...

Comment: but theere is oncreatview is there u have mention on-create  method

Comment: public class FragmentLifenews extends SherlockFragment{
 public FragmentLifenews() {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_life, container, false);
  return view;
 }

}
   this is my fragment actually i have to implement in this

Comment: You have already implement so you have solve this problem or not ??

Comment: NO Problem is coming   viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPager1(getFragmentManager()))